# How can I print a subscript like E_{n} with ZPL II?

Tags: printing, subscript, zpl-ii

I want to send a String to the Zebra printer in which I have e.g. the energy E_{N} printed whereas N must be a subscript of E. I can send strings to the printer which are in a normal format (e.g. 'bla=7'), but I have no idea how to include this subscript. Up to now I have strings like '^FDbla^FS'

I searched for the problem but could only find a solution for fixed problems like ^2, which were solved with a special character. There was no general solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print price without specyfing location of every part of the text? (ZPL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210346/how-to-print-price-without-specyfing-location-of-every-part-of-the-text-zpl)

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to strip out the subscripts and print them on the next half-line down.

```
^XA
^FT78,76^A0N,28,28^FH_^FDH  PO ^FS
^FT78,90^A0N,28,28^FH_^FD  3    4^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer. Thank you and I did it like this. It worked