# How to print price without specyfing location of every part of the text? (ZPL)

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

The effect he wants to get is:

- The price is normally printed
- Near the price I want to print the rest of the price in superscript
- At the end I want to place currency in subscript.

[image: price label]

The problem is that I don't want to specify the location of every part of text.

```
^XA
^PW480
^FS
^JMA
^MMT
^LS0
^MTD
^CI28
^FO40,11
^FWN
^CF0,16.2,20.7
^FD2144
^FS
^CI28
^FO80,10
^FWN
^CF0,8,8
^FD00
^FS
^CI28
^FO100,10
^FWN^CF0,16.2,17.25
^FDEUR
^FS
^XZ
```

So the question is that possible to print text after text specifying location only once? Without specifying location to every part of the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `^FT` instead of `^FO`, and only specify the X coordinate for the first `^FT`.

By default, `^FT` resumes at the point where the previous formatting operation finished, and you can provide a manual override to the X and Y components separately, so you would only provide the Y override for the subsequent `^FT`s and let it calculate the X automatically:

```
^FT40,11^A0,16.2,20.7^FD2144^FS
^FT,6^A0,8,8^FD00^FS
^FT,11^A0,16.2,17.25^FDEUR^FS
```

Note that you will need to adjust the Y coordinate down, because `^FO` lines up with the top of the text line (letters hanging from it) and `^FT` lines up with the bottom (letters standing on it).

Also note that `^CF` changes the printer-wide default font, and there is no point to use it before each command. Use `^A` instead as shown. You don't need to set `^CI` before each command either, it is again a global setting for encoding of the entire label text.

Comment: It works but why the rest of the price "00" goes to subscript?

Comment: I have on more question. Its possible to to it without setting the Y manually? Its hard to set position of "00" part.

Comment: @Enteee No, it's not. There is no concept of supersript, you are just printing in smaller font shifting it upwards.

Comment: Ok. But it's hard to set it when the font is size is changing..
I will have to come up with something